# Google Apps Script returning a null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google apps script function that is pulling data from a spreadsheet. It is able to log the information happily and then I return the data to a javascript function. But when I try to stringify and alert the information it alerts "null".

Not sure where I am going wrong!

Javascript calling the GAS function:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getNews).getTheNews();
```

GAS function:

```
function getTheNews(){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
 var ws = ss.getSheetByName("NewsFeed"); 
  
 
  var theNews = ws.getRange(3, 2, ws.getLastRow()-2, 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(theNews);
  
 return theNews;
 
}
```

The GAS log:
[image]

Javascript function receiving the info:

```
function getNews(theNews){
var mystr = JSON.stringify(theNews);
            alert(mystr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, the date object cannot be directly returned from Google Apps Script side to Javascript side. Also I could replicate your situation. I think that this is the reason of your issue. So as the current workaround, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

In this modification, the date object is converted to the string and sent to Javascript side. At Javascript side, the date string is converted to the date object.

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getNews).getTheNews();

function getNews(theNews){
  theNews = theNews.map(r => r.map(c => new Date(c)));  // Added
  var mystr = JSON.stringify(theNews);
  alert(mystr);
}
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function getTheNews(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("NewsFeed");
  var theNews = ws.getRange(3, 2, ws.getLastRow()-2, 1).getValues();
  return theNews.map(r => r.map(c => c.toISOString()));  // Modified
}
```

- I think that in this case, `c.getTime()` instead of `c.toISOString()` can be also used.

### Note:

- For example, if you want to retrieve the display values on the cells, you can also modify as follows. In this case, Javascript is not required to be modified.

  - From

    ```
      var theNews = ws.getRange(3, 2, ws.getLastRow()-2, 1).getValues();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var theNews = ws.getRange(3, 2, ws.getLastRow()-2, 1).getDisplayValues();
    ```
- Also I found this issue at the Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140447157) But when I saw the status, it seems "Won't Fix (Intended behavior)".

### References:

- [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)